# Предупреждение x509 при билде образа с Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, redhat, rhel

При попытки сбилдить образ выводится данное предупреждение:

```
Step 1/17: FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:2.2
Trying to pull repository mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet ...
Get https://mcr.microsoft.com/v1/_ping: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Я пробовал перезапускать Docker, также обновлять сертификаты посредством комманды `update-ca-trust`, но это ничего не дало, проблема не устранилась. Что можно сделать чтобы образ сбилдился без данной проблемы?

Comment: А с часами на компе всё ок?

Comment: А какой дистр-то?

Comment: @donRumata с часами на компе все норм, Docker на linux в частности Red Hat 7

Comment: @don Rumata с часами на компе все норм, Docker на linux в частности Red Hat 7

Comment: А если внутри свежего лтс бубна сделать то же самое?